# how to build a tick box with rails on view/index

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a tick box section with rails on view/index,these are all the steps I've taken so far i know that i need to do something about routes.rb, can you help?

this is the view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Coupon</th>
          <th>first_name</th>
          <th>surname</th>
          <th>email</th>
          <th>occupation</th>
          <th>validation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @scooties_coupons.each do |scooties_coupon| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.coupon %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.surname %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.email %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.occupation %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Mark as Valid", method: :patch %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

(i know to mark as valid should use link to but i am not too sure where to link to)

```
 create_table "scooties_coupons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "coupon"
    t.boolean "redeemed", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email"
    t.integer "expires_in"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "surname"
    t.string "oppcupation"
    t.string "occupation"
    t.boolean "validated"
    t.index ["coupon"], name: "index_scooties_coupons_on_coupon"
  end
```

(I've also created the validated as boolean in the db)

this is the controller:

```
def update

     @scooties_coupon = ScootiesCoupon.find(scooties_coupon_params)
     @scooties_coupon.update( scooties_coupon_params
    redirect_to scooties_coupons_new_path

  end


  def scooties_coupon_params
    params.require(:scooties_coupon).permit(:first_name, :surname, :email, :occupation)

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. It is in fact not so simple to do. You want to edit (one attribute from) multiple records in one form.

With a little poking, I came up with the following:

In `app/views/scooties_coupons/index.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Scooties Coupons</h1>

<%= form_with(url: validate_coupons_path, method: 'patch') do |f| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Valid</th>
        <th>Coupon</th>
        <th>Redeemed</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @scooties_coupons.each do |scooties_coupon| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= fields_for('scooties_coupons[]', scooties_coupon) do |cf|
              cf.check_box(:validated)
            end %>
          </td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.coupon %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.redeemed %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', scooties_coupon %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_scooties_coupon_path(scooties_coupon) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', scooties_coupon, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Scooties Coupon', new_scooties_coupon_path %>
```

Contains a few tricks:

- The `form_with(url: validate_coupons_path, method: 'patch')` sets-up a patch message to the server on submit.
- The

```
fields_for('scooties_coupons[]', scooties_coupon) do |cf|
  cf.check_box(:validated)
end
```

sets-up a check box for an entry. When you check the output HTML you find two fields as follows:

```
<input name="scooties_coupons[1][validated]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked"
 name="scooties_coupons[1][validated]"
 id="scooties_coupons_1_validated">
```

- The `<%= f.submit %>` submit button

In `app/controllers/scotties_coupons_controller.rb`:

```
def set_valid_coupons
  to_valid = params[:scooties_coupons].select do |id, attrs|
    attrs[:validated] == '1'
  end
  to_not_valid = params[:scooties_coupons].reject do |id, attrs|
    attrs[:validated] == '1'
  end
  ScootiesCoupon.transaction do
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_valid.keys, validated: false).update_all(
      validated:true)
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_not_valid.keys, validated: true).update_all(
      validated:false)
  end
  redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Validations updated'
end
```

is a scraping of the params to make two updates that set and clear the `validated` flags on the records such that they correspond to what was patched.

First, `to_valid` contains a selection of the params that have the `validated` check box checked.

Next, `to_not_valid` contains a selection of the params that do not have the `validated` box checked. When the `validated` attribute has value, "1" it is checked. This code treats any other value as *not* checked.

The `ScootiesCoupon.transaction do` block makes the two
updates that it contains virtually atomic in the sense that, if the second fails, ActiveRecord will roll back the first.

The first update selects records that both have:

- a key matching the ones with the `validated` box checked
- a current value of validated as `false`

It updates those records to value of validated as `true`

The second update selects records that both have:

- a key matching the ones with the `validated` box not checked
- a current value of validated as `true`

It updates those records to value of validated as `false`

By only updating records that need changing, that don't already match the values of the check boxes, the code avoids updating every record in the table. In truth, however, if there are that many records in the table, the index view is going to become quite unwieldy. With hundreds or thousands of coupons there will be quite a bit of rendering for the browser and scrolling for the person administering validations. That is a different problem and different question.

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :scooties_coupons
  patch 'validate_coupons', to: 'scooties_coupons#set_valid_coupons'
end
```

adds the controller action for patching up the records.

The index displays as, for example:
[image: Scooties Coupons index form screen shot]

On submit, the server console outputs:

```
Started PATCH "/validate_coupons" for ::1 at 2019-06-25 17:12:58 -0300
Processing by ScootiesCouponsController#set_valid_coupons as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6Rk...rA==",
   "scooties_coupons"=>{
     "1"=>{"validated"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"validated"=>"0"},
     "3"=>{"validated"=>"0"}, "4"=>{"validated"=>"1"}
  }, "commit"=>"Save "}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:60
  ScootiesCoupon Update All (0.4ms)  UPDATE "scooties_coupons"
 SET "validated" = 1
 WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" IN (?, ?)
 AND "scooties_coupons"."validated" = ?
  [["id", 1], ["id", 4], ["validated", 0]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:61
  ScootiesCoupon Update All (0.2ms)  UPDATE "scooties_coupons"
 SET "validated" = 0
 WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" IN (?, ?)
 AND "scooties_coupons"."validated" = ?
  [["id", 2], ["id", 3], ["validated", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:63
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:60
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/scooties_coupons?notice=Validations+updated
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

There are other tricks to get the record to update when the box is checked or unchecked, without the submit, via AJAX; however, starting with a submitted form gets most of the way there without that complication. The AJAX way is quite a bit of a complication, I'm afraid.

Find:

- Rails API 5.2.3 documentation for `check_box` at https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box
- Rails 5.2 guidance about dealing with forms in Rails at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/form_helpers.html

These haven't changed much in a very long time; so are likely relevant.

As an aside, the following implementation of the controller method might look tempting:

```
def set_valid_coupons
  update_params = {}
  params.require(:scooties_coupons).each do |id, attrs|
    update_params[id] = attrs.permit(:validated)
  end
  if (ScootiesCoupon.update(update_params.keys, update_params.values))
    redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Validations updated'
  else
    redirect_to action: :index, alert: 'Updates failed'
  end
end
```

However note that causes several commands to the database *per record*, as follows:

```
Started PATCH "/validate_coupons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-25 15:33:29 -0300
Processing by ScootiesCouponsController#set_valid_coupons as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2Ecnb8Sy/5L4m9wW+4QlSS5WXQTCUh92ALRcv9w69OGRiov/Z95ReX9tGBn7UNN/NXSl83PeKs8cIkLaGhAoDg==", "scooties_coupons"=>{"1"=>{"validated"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"validated"=>"0"}, "3"=>{"validated"=>"0"}, "4"=>{"validated"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Save "}
  ScootiesCoupon Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "scooties_coupons".* FROM "scooties_coupons" WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
  ScootiesCoupon Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "scooties_coupons".* FROM "scooties_coupons" WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
  ScootiesCoupon Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "scooties_coupons".* FROM "scooties_coupons" WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
  ScootiesCoupon Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "scooties_coupons".* FROM "scooties_coupons" WHERE "scooties_coupons"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/scooties_coupons_controller.rb:48
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/scooties_coupons?notice=Validations+updated
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: hi @Douglas thanks so much for your answer! I am trying to have an index page which is like a spreadsheet that has a tick box at the side.

Comment: hi @Douglas thank you so much! this is so very helpful - i will have a look now!!!

Comment: hi Douglas, i dont really get this bit here : ``` ScootiesCoupon.transaction do
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_valid.keys, validated: false).update_all(
      validated:true)
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_not_valid.keys, validated: true).update_all(
      validated:false)
  end```

Comment: This is very helpful to me without having to create a new field as checkbox, thank you! I have a question in regard to the checkbox - when the email is validated it will be stored into db as true and the ticked row will be disabled as it no longer can being ticked?(disabled?) any idea how to implement that on this case?

Comment: Hi @gina. Thank you for your questions. There's an edit with explanation about the use of `transaction`. The question about hiding check boxes under certain circumstances is really a new question. However, you can conditionally render them. Probably you don't put that business logic in the view, although that's tempting and easy to do.

Comment: hi, @Douglas thank you so much for answering!! i was wondering would you mind explaining the codes in the scootiescoupon controller method.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt. The answer now contains further explanation of the controller code rather than hand waving with "pretty straightforward". Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer too! could you please maybe showcase the disabled/hiding checkboxes function for me, please?

Comment: or you'd think i should ask a new question fro that? :)

Comment: Hi @gina. No problem regarding the prompt response. I'm trying to solve a JS packaging issue I have with help from SO and the in-box pulses red. With regard to the disabling, hiding. That feels like another question to me. The answer is already quite long and detailed. Adding an answer around adding this business logic would cause it to be much longer and less focussed. Please pardon me asking for a pass on that one. If you like, consider asking it as a new question.

Comment: Hi @Douglas, thank you so much! for some reasons for the question I've asked previously doesn't allow me to ask question lately- could you have a look of this link? thx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832650/how-to-disable-checkbox-on-condition