# how to disable checkbox on condition?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a spreadsheet on index page to display items with checkbox and if validated - the checkbox will be disabled so that people won't mis-ticked it.I was wondering should i do it with controller or the view? thanks : can you help?

In app/views/scooties_coupons/index.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-hover">

<h1>Scooties Coupons</h1>

<%= form_with(url: validate_coupons_path, method: 'patch') do |f| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Valid</th>
        <th>Coupon</th>
        <th>Redeemed</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>occupation</th>
        <th>validation</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @scooties_coupons.each do |scooties_coupon| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= fields_for('scooties_coupons[]', scooties_coupon) do |cf|
              cf.check_box(:validated)
            end %>
          </td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.coupon %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.redeemed %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.surname %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.email %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.occupation %></td>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<br>

</table>
```

in app/controllers/scotties_coupons_controller.rb:

```
def set_valid_coupons
  to_valid = params[:scooties_coupons].select do |id, attrs|
    attrs[:validated] == '1'
  end
  to_not_valid = params[:scooties_coupons].reject do |id, attrs|
    attrs[:validated] == '1'
  end
  ScootiesCoupon.transaction do
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_valid.keys, validated: false).update_all(
      validated:true)
    ScootiesCoupon.where(id: to_not_valid.keys, validated: true).update_all(
      validated:false)
  end
  redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Validations updated'
end
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you have a specific problem? Is there an error? And – because you tagged your question with rails 3 and rails 4 – what version of Rails do you actually use?

Comment: hi @spickermann sorry i was using version 3 actually and my question was should i do it with controller or view? thx

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/56741193/608359 the comment describes some business logic around validating the email address, "when the email is validated it will be stored into db as true and the ticked row will be disabled." Is that applicable to this question?

Comment: hi @DouglasLovell, yes

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
<table class="table table-hover">

<h1>Scooties Coupons</h1>

<%= form_with(url: validate_coupons_path, method: 'patch') do |f| %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Valid</th>
        <th>Coupon</th>
        <th>Redeemed</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>occupation</th>
        <th>validation</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @scooties_coupons.each do |scooties_coupon| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <% if true %>
                SOMETHING HERE 
            <% else %>
              <%= fields_for('scooties_coupons[]', scooties_coupon) do |cf|
                cf.check_box(:validated)
              end %>

            <% end %>
          </td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.coupon %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.redeemed %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.surname %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.email %></td>
          <td><%= scooties_coupon.occupation %></td>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<br>

</table>
```